# Read a Response in ActionFilter then DelegatingHandlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Should we always read from `HttpContent` as a stream and then reset? We were reading twice from the response and it wasn't working [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclitus#cite_ref-6)].

We were trying to log an HTTP response with an `ActionFilterAttribute` and then update the response in a `DelegatingHandler`. The changes made in the `DelegatingHandler` were lost: the reponse that arrived back at the client was unaltered.

```cs
public sealed class LoggingFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        string logMessage = null;
        context.Response?.Content?
            .ReadAsStringAsync()
            .ContinueWith(task => logMessage = task.Result);
        ...
    }
}
```

```cs
internal class AddVersionsHandler : DelegatingHandler
{       
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        var responseContent = 
            await response.Content
                .ReadAsAsync<IOurModels>(cancellationToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        responseContent.Versions = this.Versions;

        return response;
     }
 }
```

Changing the read in the `ActionFilterAttribute` to read from the stream and then reset the position works. The `HttpContent` is assumed to be a stream that must be reset on each read.

```cs
public override async void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
{
    string logMessage = null;
    if (context.ActionContext?.Response?.Content != null)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await context.ActionContext.Response.Content.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        var sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
        logMessage = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    ...
}
```

Do we need to ensure that **everywhere** the `HttpContent` is read we need to read from the stream and then reset?

Chaining these `DelegatingHandlers` into the pipeline that each alter the reponse works just fine. It seems that `ReadAsAsync<T>` provides access to the underlying object in the stream without changing the read position. So if you know the object type you intend to read then this is an option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read or alter the contents of the response and you know the type of the object you can use `ReadAsAsync<T>()`. These can be chained in the pipeline if required.

```cs
var response = await context.ActionContext.Response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IOurModel>();
```

If you are logging you can then serialize the above response to XML or JSON .

If you want to read the stream as a string you can only do that once with `ReadAsStringAsync()`. Later updates in the pipeline will be lost.

```cs
string logMessage = null;
context.Response?.Content?
    .ReadAsStringAsync()
    .ContinueWith(task => logMessage = task.Result);
```

If you want to read the stream and later do anything else at all to it you must reset the position.

```cs
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
await context.ActionContext.Response.Content.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
var logMessage = sr.ReadToEnd();
```